# Access Runtime 2013 on WinXP?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2013 app that I have converted to a 2013 Runtime App.  It runs just fine in an Office 2007 or even NO Office environment.

I have 29 users in India all running WinXP.  My fear is Access 2013 Runtime will not install on these machines.

I attempted to rebuild the app in Access 2010, calling the necessary references, importing forms/tables/code then running thru Access 2010 Runtime.  My app DOES NOT run in this RT configuration.  Complains:  "...VBA Project contained cannot be read..."

I have narrowed the issue down to something in my default display Form.  If I replace with a simple form & button, I do not get this message.  If I attempt to OPEN my intended startup form from that button, THEN I get the message.

I've backed out my 64bit/32bit checks - no change.  I do a command shell (ping) to check if SQL server is reachable, but nothing else terribly exotic in the startup form.

Any suggestions what else to look for?

Best solution would be if Access 2013 Runtime will install on these XP machines (not tried yet).  I don't have a copy to test on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of thrashing and pulling out my hair, I found a couple Access 2010 Runtime patches (SP1, SP2).  Installed these onto a WinXP machine, RT APP is now happy - no issues whatsoever.  The current 2010 Runtime D/L from MS does not have these folded in yet...

SP1:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2460015

SP2:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687444

Yeesh, that was painful.

Answer (score 1):

From the Microsoft website for the [Access 2013 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=39358):

> Supported Operating System
>
> Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012

This doesn't mean that Access 2013 Runtime *won't* run on XP, but it is *not supported*, meaning that if you can get it to install and have any problems, Microsoft won't help you.

On the other hand, Windows XP support [is going to end on April 8 2014](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/end-support-help), so your Indian users may be well advised to update their OS, but you can't count on that happening, especially in India...

You could also try using `Application.SaveAsText` on your offending form on Access 2013, and using `Application.LoadFromText` in Access 2010 on the resultant text file.  If this doesn't work, the text file is human-readable, and you may be able to figure out what is incompatible from that.

Comment: We are already on them about the WinXP EOL and security concerns, but nearterm prospects don't bode well for hardware/software upgrades.

Comment: I tried the .SaveAsText and noticed an odd carriage break in a combobox rowsource:

Name ="cmbUser"
RowSourceType ="Table/Query"
RowSource ="SELECT Users.Username, Users.UserID, Users.Email, Users.LastNam"
"e, Users.FirstName, Users.Location FROM Users ORDER BY Users.Username; "

Comment: sorry about pesky word wrapping above.  Anyway.  I corrected the beak and imported back in.  Same issue.  I was so hopeful!

Comment: India will attempt 2013 install for tomorrow morning; fingers crossed

Comment: The line break isn't likely relevant. It is more likely to be related to a feature that is new to Access 2013.  If you can run both Access 2010 and 2013 side-by-side, you could try copy-paste from 2013 to 2010...

Comment: OK, I created a most basic 2010 app, 1 table, 1 form, 1 combo box, no added references.  Fails in the same manner in RT 2010.  Losing my mind on this one!  Re-installing RT on both dvt machine and destination VM.